# Option "Add NuGet packages" not available/greyed out

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

When I create a Xamarin forms project in Visual Studio for Mac, the option "Add NuGet packages" is not available:

[image]

I need it to add JSON and HTTP packages.
The project is not running or in debug mode, and I already tried to restart the project, but that didn't help. Any idea why it is not available?

Comment: In the windows version, a restore is sometimes needed before you can add. Have you tried to restore the packages?

Comment: Another thing? are you currently debugging? If so, you should stop that first.

Comment: restoring packages doesn't make any difference and I am not debugging

Comment: What kind of project is it? Shared Project won't support that if I remember correctly. You need to use .NET Standard.

Comment: It should just work. What surprises me is that "Edit References" is also grayed-out.

Comment: t is solved, I used "Use shared library" when creating the solution, when I select "Use portable class library" then the NuGet options are available. @Lex Li if you add your comment as solution, I will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin cross platform development has three options,

- [Shared Projects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/#Shared_Projects)
- [Portable Class Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/#Portable_Class_Libraries)
- [.NET Standard Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/#Net_Standard)

The greyed out menu item is an indicator that you are using Shared Projects. It makes sense as Shared Projects is an option without using NuGet packages.

Shared Projects and PCL were the old approaches when there was no better solution. .NET Standard 2.0 published in 2017 was a milestone and the whole .NET ecosystem is now moving toward it。

So if possible, use the .NET Standard approach. Shared Projects might still be used in certain (and rare) scenarios, but PCL is clearly obsolete.